# Setting up a Websocket Server without running a Daemon

Tags: php, apache, websocket

This might look like a simple question, but it's boggling my mind: Assume I can't run Daemons, **how would I set up a websocket server?**

(Details: Apache 2.2.21, PHP 5.3.9, so preferably with PHP)

Comment: Still need daemon.. like ZeroMQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By not wanting daemons I assume you are asking for something that runs in Apache/PHP rather than as a standalone program/server that you have to run.

Note that PHP does not yet have a good option that support the old Hixie WebSocket protocol and the newer HyBi/IETF protocol at the same time (most other languages have a server that supports both).

- http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/ only supports the older Hixie protocol. This is good for iOS devices (iPhone and iPads).
- http://code.google.com/p/php-websocket-server/ only supports the newer HyBi/IETF protocol which the latest versions of most other browsers support.

If you are willing to consider non-PHP options, these projects can be integrated into Apache and support both revisions of the protocol:

- **Python**: http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/
- **C**: https://github.com/disconnect/apache-websocket

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/

Servers need to run as daemons... what's the point of a server otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/ can help you.

From the howto:

```
// Server side
log("Handshaking...");
list($resource,$host,$origin) = getheaders($buffer);
$upgrade = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
       "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n" .
       "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
       "WebSocket-Origin: " . $origin . "\r\n" .
       "WebSocket-Location: ws://" . $host . $resource . "\r\n" .
       "\r\n";
$handshake = true;
socket_write($socket,$upgrade.chr(0),strlen($upgrade.chr(0)));


// Client side
var host = "ws://localhost:12345/websocket/server.php";
try{
  socket = new WebSocket(host);
  log('WebSocket - status '+socket.readyState);
  socket.onopen    = function(msg){ log("Welcome - status "+this.readyState); };
  socket.onmessage = function(msg){ log("Received: "+msg.data); };
  socket.onclose   = function(msg){ log("Disconnected - status "+this.readyState);     };
}
catch(ex){ log(ex); }
```

Answer (score -1):

you could potentially run your "server" as a long-polled apache request. you could use a normal web browser to start/control it, but you could also use telnet or curl. it would be hacky compared to a proper systemd service, but it would work

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to be more concise... you are giving too many options so try to explain them better.